# USB flash drive showing up as two devices (not! two partitions) on Linux

Tags: linux, usb-drive

When plugging in a particular USB flash drive, it is showing up as two *devices*, `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`, not as a single device with multiple partitions.  Here's the  log:

```
[142161.806978] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[142161.956580] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6387, bcdDevice= 1.02
[142161.956582] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[142161.956583] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: C3C512C9
[142161.957547] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[142161.957747] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[142162.987691] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB 2.0  Flash Disk       8.08 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[142162.988189] scsi 4:0:0:1: Direct-Access     USB 2.0  Flash Disk       8.09 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[142162.988598] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[142162.988866] sd 4:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[142162.989082] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 246144 512-byte logical blocks: (126 MB/120 MiB)
[142162.989225] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[142162.989226] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[142162.989364] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[142162.989367] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[142162.989999] sd 4:0:0:1: [sdc] 5760 512-byte logical blocks: (2.95 MB/2.81 MiB)
[142162.990143] sd 4:0:0:1: [sdc] Write Protect is on
[142162.990146] sd 4:0:0:1: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 80 00
[142162.990414] sd 4:0:0:1: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[142162.990419] sd 4:0:0:1: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[142163.002004]  sdb: sdb1
[142163.003225] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[142163.013711]  sdc: sdc1
[142163.014811] sd 4:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

And as suggested in the comments, the results of running `file -s`:

```
# file -s  /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xc, start-CHS (0x0,32,33), end-CHS (0xf,75,60), startsector 2048, 243712 sectors, extended partition table (last)

# file -s  /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0x1, start-CHS (0x0,2,1), end-CHS (0x16,3,32), startsector 64, 5696 sectors, extended partition table (last)
```

I've never seen something like this before. Other than tossing the flash drive and getting another one, is there some means of making it show up as a single device?

Thanks,
Diab

**Update:**
As suggested by @telcoM, I've tried running the `u3-tool` against the devices:

```
# u3-tool -D /dev/sdb
u3_partition_info() failed: Device reported command failed: status 1
Data partition info:
 - Data partition size: 715190086144 byte(0x53425355)
 - Secured zone size: 49068032 byte(0x0001765c)
 - Unlocked: 0x00000010
 - Password try: 0x20b2a600

Chip info:
 - Manufacturer: 
 - Revision: USBS]v

u3_read_device_property() failed for property 0x03: Header of property 0x0003 could not be read.
u3_read_device_property() failed for property 0x0C: Header of property 0x000C could not be read.
# u3-tool -D /dev/sdc
Error opening device: Read-only file system
```

An attempt to make `/dev/sdc` writeable via `hdparam` doesn't seem to work:

```
# hdparm -r /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 readonly      =  1 (on)
# hdparm -r0 /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 readonly      =  0 (off)
# u3-tool -D /dev/sdc
Error opening device: Read-only file system
```

Comment: `sudo file -s /dev/sdc1` ? If it's ISO then I see no issue.

Comment: running `file -s` on both partitions gives me:
`/dev/sdc1: DOS/MBR boot sector, [...]`
`/dev/sdb1: DOS/MBR boot sector,[...]`

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Apologies; I've added that to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have a special [U3 "smart" USB flash drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U3_(software)). Such a flash drive would present itself as two devices: one normal writeable disk device, and one (usually smaller and read-only) device typically containing an ISO-9660 filesystem, effectively emulating a CD-ROM.

This functionality was aimed for Microsoft Windows and is basically useless for other operating systems. Your Linux distribution should have an optional package named `u3-tool` or something similar: it contains a command-line tool with the same name, that can be used to change the split between the two devices, or to remove the second device entirely, allowing the full capacity of the USB drive to be used like a plain old USB flash drive.

In this specific case, the second storage device is just 2.81 MiB, which makes me think it might be designed to be used as an USB floppy drive emulator instead, to enable booting from USB on old systems with very limited USB boot support. If that's true, it might pre-date the U3 specification and be completely unconfigurable without chip-specific hardware development tools.

By your `file -s /dev/sdc` result, it looks like the second device currently contains a regular MBR partition table, but you might be able to just write a floppy image to `/dev/sdc` with `dd` and then use that device as an USB floppy emulator for an old computer that requires one to boot from USB.

```
[142161.956580] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6387, bcdDevice= 1.02
```

According to [USB ID Repository](https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/), the vendor ID 058f belongs to Alcor Micro Corp., and the product ID 6387 is just "Flash Drive", although there is also a mention of a Transcend JetFlash flash drive having the same ID. It might be a OEM USB drive chip that is used by various drive manufacturers as-is.

It might also be a cheap fake product that will at first glance show a greater capacity when checked with Microsoft Windows, but the Linux kernel indicates the larger part as having the capacity of just 126 MB. Today, a name-brand USB stick with 32 GB (= 32000 MB) capacity should cost about $8, so it's probably not worth it to spend very much effort on this one.

Comment: That sounds very much like what I've got, although the `u3-tool` isn't helping much (i've attached the output to the OP). so it may be pre-U3 as you mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like `u3-tool` reports nonsensical values and indicates a command failure, so the device must be pre-U3. Based on the total size alone, it must be pretty old (and/or very, very cheap). The raw (unpartitioned) size of the second device is 5760 blocks, which matches *exactly* the size of an old 3.5" ED floppy disk. That would be the largest possible USB-based boot device for a system that can only use "USB floppy" protocol to boot from USB. The second device seems to be hardware write-protected, so its current contents might offer some clues about the intended use.

Comment: The write-protected part might even be pre-programmed at factory as a helpdesk/laptop support tool, containing something like a BIOS updater or a BIOS password reset master key for some particular model/series of laptops. Or it might be a reasonably tamper-proof delivery device for firmware upgrades or feature unlocks for some industrial automation device, in which case the drive may be cheap but the files inside may have once been very expensive indeed.